# Applescript for VyprVPN

Tags: applescript

I am news at applescript. In the dictionary from VyprVPN I found this command. Have tried to convert this into an apple script but I do not get it to work:

Connect v : Connect to VyprVPN host with protocol

Connect

```
 protocol pptp/‌openvpn160/‌openvpn256/‌L2TP/‌chameleon/‌most_secure : VPN protocol
 host text : Host name
```

This is what I made of it, but it does not work...

```
global host

global protocol

set protocol to "protocol pptp/‌openvpn160/‌openvpn256/‌L2TP/‌chameleon/‌most_secure"

set host to "us4.vpn.goldenfrog.com"

tell application "VyprVPN"  

Connect

end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use this Application, but I'll give it a try:

```
tell application "VyprVPN"  

    Connect most_secure "us4.vpn.goldenfrog.com"

end tell
```

Just a try...